# Mongosh Aggregate: Access to variable ROOT disallowed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I am using aggregation in mongodb to group using multiple conditions, and want to return all field document not just the field that I used to group, thus I am using $$ROOT

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$group": { _id: {firstName: "$firstName", lastName: "$lastName"}, doc: {$last: "$$ROOT"} } },
    { "$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$doc"} },
    { $sort: {_id:1} }
])
```

When I run this in mongo shell theres a result it works as I wanted, however when put exactly the same in my code that runs using Mongosh 1.8.0, error says:
`TypeError: csfle "analyze_query" failed: Access to variable ROOT disallowed [Error 2, code 31127]`

I tried to remove the $$ROOT it works, but I dont want just the fields I used in grouping, I want ALL the field in documents. What could be the problem? Why ROOT is disallowed?

Comment: Try the latest version (1.10.1 at the time of writing). If that didn't work then open a bug report with the vendor